# no fonts available for @font-face rule microsoft edge fonts.com

Tags: css, fonts, microsoft-edge

I am getting a
CSS3120: No fonts available for @font-face rule
for the new Microsoft Edge browser on windows 10.

The fonts I am using are from fonts.com and have the normal declarations that I would expect (e.g. woff, ttf, svg etc).

```
{
font-family:"myfont";
src:url("/dv2/2/asdf.eot?asdf#iefix");
src:url("/dv2/2/asdf.eot?asdf#iefix") format("eot"),url("/dv2/14/asdf.woff2?asdf") format("woff2"),url("/dv2/3/asdf.woff?asdf") format("woff"),url("/dv2/1/asdf.ttf?asdf") format("truetype"),url("/dv2/11/asdf.svg?asdf") format("svg");
}
```

The sites still work normally on chrome, firefox, and IE for windows 10.  my fonts that I used from Icomoon that are on my domain and fonts from google fonts seem to work fine on the edge browser.  Anybody else having this problem with fonts.com?

Comment: same problem here, I use fonts.com also on WP websites, same damn issue!

Comment: same here, I downloaded Roboto fonts from Google and load them locally using Google's stylesheet, see my gist: https://gist.github.com/benoror/2d5344910aa2a7287efd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted fonts.com and the solution they gave - which did seem to work for me - was to republish the project.  If you go into manage webfonts and to the project, there is a republish button. It will probably take a couple minutes and then it should work.

Answer (score 6):

I was using a local version of Google Fonts like one of the commenters, @benoror. My issue ended up being that I used references to `woff2` fonts. Edge [doesn't support the woff2 format yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff2).

My solution was to switch back to loading the fonts from Google Fonts since they have logic based on the user-agent that determines which font files get referenced in the `@font-face` declarations.

Another option would have been to use regular `woff` instead of `woff2`: http://caniuse.com/#search=woff

Comment: Microsoft Edge [supports WOFF2 as of version 14316](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/wofffileformat20).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue,

After reading [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530757(v=vs.85).aspx) and adding `local` parameter error disappeared.

`src:url(sURL) format(fontFormat) local(fontName)`